# How would the Hutts have settled the bet between Watto and Qui-Gon?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

Say that Watto agreed to allow the Hutts to settle the bet between himself and Qui-Gon.

What method would the Hutts use to settle such a bet?  There were no witnesses, no paper agreements... just a handshake.  How would they determine justice?

Why was Watto so fearful of going to the Hutts?

Comment: The same way that judges settle verbal contracts in the real world, by using their best judgement.

Comment: with rancors :)

Comment: How would the Hutts have settled the bet between Watto and Qui-Gon? Very well, thank you! :)

Comment: Whoever pays the Hutt more, wins.

Comment: They would have sat on them

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. ***Out of universe:***

   The reason Watto was afraid of going to the Hutts had very little to do with the bet.

   It was answered by someone from entirely different fictional universe, namely, the Rabbi from *Fidder on the Roof*:

   > G-d, bless the Tzar, and **keep him far, far away from us**.

   In other words, it's a **really**, **really**, **really** Good Idea not to show up on Hutt's - or any crime lord's - radar in the first place; and **especially** not to owe Hutts a favor (a lesson several people in *Godfather* failed to learn in time).
2. ***In-Universe:***

   - Watto was worried that things were already going too smoothly for Qui-Gon in unlikely situations (Watto losing the cube throw, Anakin winning the race), and he would somehow have a trick to get Hutts to side with him:

     > The Toydarian shoved his snout against Qui-Gon’s nose. “You can’t have him! It wasn’t a fair bet!”
     >
     > Qui-Gon looked him up and down with a chilly stare. “Would you like to discuss it with the Hutts? I’m sure they would be happy to settle the matter.”
     >
     > Watto jerked as if stung, his beady eyes filled with hate. “No, no! **I want no more of your tricks**.” He gestured emphatically. “Take the boy! Be gone!”

Comment: +1.  I don't know how I should feel about an out-of-canon answer, but I think it is so apropos that its hard not to accept.  A truth in any reality is worth more than any fact in a specific world!

Comment: @CortAmmon - better?

Comment: Side note: I know that someone posted an answer upvoted to stratosphere because it quoted Wookiepedia and IMDB to the effect that the cube for gambling was cheating-loaded. **THAT ANSWER IS WRONG!!!** This was made up by Wookiepedia and isn't in any canon.

Answer (score 7):

Watto won Anakin (and Shmii) from Gardulla the Hutt.

Assuming this is the Hutt they would go see, Gardulla would likely not be pleased to see Watto, considering she had lost to him the very slaves he was now petitioning to keep as a result of a bet. She would not be the most impartial judge and would possibly have a keen sense of *schadenfreude* from the situation.

This also of course presumes that Watto's acquisition of them was legitimate to begin with. He may not want to waltz in with slaves he stole.

Comment: Well actually Jabba took control of Tatooine from Gardulla Some time before the events of the Phantom Menace and since it's actually Jabba we see start the race it's safe to assume that they would actually be seeing Jabba and not Gardulla

Comment: @TheMandolirian Gardulla is seen at the race behind Jabba. Also - what's the canon source for the Jabba / Tatooine control?